# Series order specification is not a machine-sized integer

Tags: replacement

Running the code:

```
Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, val}] /. val -> 10
```

Gives the error

```
Series::serlim: Series order specification val is not a machine-sized integer. >>
```

The help file says that instead of `val`, I shouldn't be using a symbol but an integer. But I want `val` because I need to apply two values.

```
Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, val}] /. val -> {10, 20}
```

Which I can't.

I did try to use `Refine` and thus tell Mathematica that its an integer but it didn't work.

```
Refine[Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, val}], Element[val, Integers]] /. val -> 10
```

Any suggestions about how I can do it without running it twice?

Comment: `Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 20}] // {# + O[x]^11, #} &`

Comment: Try `Quiet[Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, val}]] /. Map[{val -> #} &, {10, 20}]`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the following

> Unevaluated[Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, val}]] /. val -> 10

But still it does not work for a list of values as `Series` does not thread over list. So in order to be able to use it for multiple arguments you need something like

> Series[Sinc[x], {x, 0, #}]& /@ {10,20}